# How to use Powershell write-progress parameter with unknown seconds remaining to complete

Tags: powershell

Trying to show approximate unknown time to finish the Write-process in PowerShell 'for' loop.
Write-process have a parameter '-SecondsRemaining' to show remaining time below progress bar with text 'remaining'. Bit not able to show remaining time to finish the loop.

Failed attempts

($i-$_) increments the time with each iteration with 'remaining' text, shows time elapsed

(-1-$_) not working

(10-$_) hardcoded 10 seconds

Code sample

```
for ($i=1;$i -le 10000;$i++)
{
Write-Host "Iteration $i"
Write-Progress -Activity "Write-progress with seconds remaining" -Status "$i Completed" -SecondsRemaining ($i-$_)
}
```

Some References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.2

[https://morgantechspace.com/2018/05/powershell-show-progress-bar-status-and-percent-completed.html#:~:text=PowerShell%20%3A%20Show%20Progress%20Bar%2C%20Status%20and%20%25,completed%20for%20a%20long%20running%20command%20or%20script](https://morgantechspace.com/2018/05/powershell-show-progress-bar-status-and-percent-completed.html#:%7E:text=PowerShell%20%3A%20Show%20Progress%20Bar%2C%20Status%20and%20%25,completed%20for%20a%20long%20running%20command%20or%20script).

Comment: And what is `$_` supposed to be inside a for loop? It's not a `ForEach-Object` loop you're using..

Comment: Instead of `$i-$_` do you mean `10000 - $i`?  `$i` is the variable you're incrementing every iteration, so that's the one you need to use, not `$_`.  Also, you should just use double quotes if you want that variable to be expanded inside a string: `Write-Host "Iteration $i"`.

Comment: Thanks @LanceU.Matthews, I will use double quotes, And got some improvement with using `10000 - $i `, But the time starts from 02:00:00 and finishes the run in 20seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a rough estimate by extrapolating from the elapsed time and how many items you've processed to that point:

```
$maxItems = 10000
$startTime = Get-Date

for ($i = 1; $i -le $maxItems; $i++)
{
    # Do some work
    Write-Host "Iteration $i"

    # Calculate the timings
    $elapsed = ((Get-Date) - $startTime).TotalSeconds
    $remainingItems = $maxItems - $i
    $averageItemTime = $elapsed / $i

    # Update the user
    Write-Progress -Activity "Write-progress with seconds remaining" -Status "$i Completed" -SecondsRemaining ($remainingItems * $averageItemTime)
}
```

Comment: Seconds remaining often fluctuates highly, especially when current item number is still relatively low. It might be a good idea to round to nearest multiple of N (e. g. 5 s), so the remaining seconds will update like `20, 15, 10, 5` instead of `18,20,23,21,17,15 ...` you name it. Possible formula: `[Math]::Round($secondsRemaining / 5.0) * 5`. Maybe even use a delay of a few seconds before showing the first "seconds remaining" value.

Comment: Thanks boxdog your solution and it worked, really appreciate the effort. 
And Thanks to @zett42 for the improvement in the flickering seconds number. Your formula worked and increment is happening peacefully. Like you mentioned sometimes goes back to lower number but its fine.